# Why does less than or equal return false for equal numbers?

Tags: c#, debugging, unity-game-engine

I have a simple function that returns `bool` value as a result of comparison of distance between 2 entities to GravityRadius field.

```
public bool IsEntityPulledByGravity(IEntity entity)
{
    return Vector3.Distance(State.Position, entity.State.Position) <= GravityRadius;
}
```

Sometimes it works as it suppose to but sometimes it returns incorrect `false` value. I entered debug mode to analyse it and I can't figure out why it would return false for comparison of `30 <= 30`. What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't compare floating point numbers for equality.

This MSDN article specifically describes the situation for System.Single.  [System.Single.Equals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t24f0axa(v=vs.110).aspx) under the section **Precision in Comparisons**.

Answer (score 1):

make sure whatever you are comparing are of the same datatype, you can  cast them to same datatype before comparing . Use compareTo in your case since Single class implelements  the IComparable interface check this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Both are of same type `System.Single` check screenshot.

Comment: Use comapreTo instead of equality operators